# Android Bounding Rectangles

Tags: android, imageview, bounding

I'm trying to make a bounding rectangle around an ImageView for collision detection. Unfortunately, I can only find code for sprites and not ImageViews. Is there a way to make a rectangle that goes outside of an image for an ImageView? One of the ImageViews moves through animation while the other one stays still.

Answer (score 0):

Using imageViews for move animation isn't best idea. It takes too many resources. However you can set width and height of imageView to `WRAP_CONTENT` and use sizes of ImageView as bounding rect

In your xml layout set android:layout_height and android:layout_width of your ImageView to "wrap_content". And when you need bounding rect of ImageView:

```
...
int[] l = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(l);
int x = l[0];
int y = l[1];
int w = imageView.getWidth();
int h = imageView.getHeight();
...
```

x, y, w ,h — required bounding rect in *screen coordinates*